# Any reason why this should not work? SQL will not add record to database

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

so I have another problem that blows my mind why it will not work, but you all are smarter than me so..

the code is supposed to add new records to my database, it is a budgeting program and it asks the user the date of the income they have received, the user's ID, the name and category of the income and the amount that was received, and I am using SQL to add it into a ms access database. Take a look and please help!

Here is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn8Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 iNameOfIncome, iCategory, iDate :integer;
 sDate, sAmount :string;
 dDate :TDate;
begin
 with dmRecords do
  begin
   sAmount := Edit7.Text;
   iNameOfIncome := ComboBox10.ItemIndex + 1;
   iCategory := ComboBox2.ItemIndex + 1;
   dDate := DateTimePicker1.Date;
   sDate := DateToStr(dDate);

   qryRecords.SQL.Clear;
   qryRecords.Active := False;
   qryRecords.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO [Income (Ledger)](DateofIncome, [User ID], [Income ID], [Category ID], [Income Amount]');
   qryRecords.SQL.Add('VALUES (' + sDate + ',' + IntToStr(SpinEdit2.Value) + ',' + IntToStr(iNameOfIncome) + ',' + IntToStr(iCategory) + ',' + sAmount + ')');
   qryRecords.ExecSQL;
   qryRecords.SQL.Clear;
   qryRecords.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM [Income (Ledger)] ORDER BY IncomeNo');
   qryRecords.Active := True;
  end;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems which you are missing the final  parenthesis on this line  `INSERT INTO [Income (Ledger)](DateofIncome, [User ID], [Income ID], [Category ID], [Income Amount])`, Also consider use parameters to pass the values to insert.

Comment: Again stop using concatenated statements!!! The answer shows you how to do it correctly...

Comment: I cant believe I missed that! Thank you! It works but my datepicker keeps adding the date as 1900/01/27. Any reason why it would be like that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rewrite it like this

```
  qryRecords.Close;
  qryRecords.SQL.Text :=
  'INSERT INTO [Income (Ledger)](DateofIncome, [User ID], [Income ID], [Category ID], [Income Amount]) ' +
  'VALUES (:DateofIncome,:User_ID,:Category_ID,:Income_ID,:Income_Amount)';
  qryRecords.ParamByName('DateofIncome').AsDateTIme := dDate;
  qryRecords.ParamByName('User_ID').AsInteger := SpinEdit2.Value;
  qryRecords.ParamByname('Category_ID').AsInteger := iCategory;
  qryRecords.ParamByname('Income_ID').AsInteger := iNameOfIncome;  
  qryRecords.ParamByname('Income_Amount').AsFloat:= sAmount;
  qryRecords.ExecSQL;

  qryRecords.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM [Income (Ledger)] ORDER BY IncomeNo';
  qryRecords.Open;
```

This way you will pass right types to DB. Otherwise you do not know how db will interpret what you are sending to it.

Comment: I have tried it, and it keeps telling me "Undeclared Identifier: AsDateTime", undeclared identifier: as integer etc. Im using delphi 7

Comment: Sounds like you're perhaps using ADO (TADOQuery)? In which case the parameter syntax is ParamByName('User_ID').Value := ...

Comment: If you are using ado-query I highly suggest to change it to something like ZeosLib. Because I had cases when ParamByName('XXX').Value := 1; Resulted in odd behavior because Value is variant an 1 was converted to varSmallint but db was waiting for varInteger.